# Adding charts in WatchOs

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on a POC  to implement charts in Apple Watch (Analytics for Business/Enterprise data).

For example :

[image: Watch Os app with charts]

How can I do that ?

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the info.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 16):

I found that [YOChartImageKit](https://github.com/yasuoza/YOChartImageKit). With this library you can create charts in watch os.

## Installation

**CocoaPods**

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'YOChartImageKit', '~> 1.1'
```

**Carthage**

```
github "yasuoza/YOChartImageKit" ~> 1.1
```

**CocoaSeeds**

```
# For both iOS and watchOS framework
target 'YOChartImageKit' do
   github 'yasuoza/YOChartImageKit', '1.1.0', files: 'Source/YOChartImageKit/*.{h,m}'
end
```

---

## Configuration

**Line chart solid**

[image: Line chart solid]

```
let image = YOLineChartImage()
image.strokeWidth = 4.0              // width of line
image.strokeColor = randomColor()    // color of line
image.values = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]       // chart values
image.smooth = false                 // disable smooth line
image.drawImage(frame, scale: scale) // draw an image
```

**Line chart smooth**

[image: Line chart smooth]

```
let image = YOLineChartImage()
image.strokeWidth = 4.0              // width of line
image.fillColor = randomColor()      // color of area
image.values = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]       // chart values
// image.smooth = true               // [default] draws a smooth line
image.drawImage(frame, scale: scale) // draw an image
```

**Bar chart vertical**

[image: Bar chart vertical]

```
let image = YOBarChartImage()
image.values = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]       // chart values
image.fillColor = randomColor()      // color of bars
// image.barPadding = 2.0            // [optional] padding of bars
// image.barStyle = .Vertical        // [default] draws a vertical bars
image.drawImage(frame, scale: scale) // draw an image
```

**Bar chart horizontal**

[image: Bar chart horizontal]

```
let image = YOBarChartImage()
image.values = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]       // chart values
image.fillColor = randomColor()      // color of bars
// image.barPadding = 2.0            // [optional] padding of bars
image.barStyle = .Horizontal         // draws a horizontal bars
image.drawImage(frame, scale: scale) // draw an image
```

**Donut chart**

[image: Donut chart]

```
let image = YODonutChartImage()
image.donutWidth = 16.0                           // width of donut
// image.labelText = "LABEL"                      // [optional] center label text
// image.labelColor = UIColor.whiteColor()        // [optional] center label color
image.values = [10.0, 20.0, 70.0]                 // chart values
image.colors = (0..<3).map { _ in randomColor() } // colors of pieces
image.drawImage(frame, scale: scale)              // draw an image
```

---

## Framework Requirements

```
watchOS ~> 2.0
```

## Build Requirements

```
Xcode >= 7.1
```

---

## Example Application

Example applications are available for both iOS and watchOS. You can find all file [here](https://github.com/yasuoza/YOChartImageKit)

`pod try YOChartImageKit`

or open `YOChartImageKit.xcodeproj` with Xcode and build demo app.

---

> You can find all the documentation on the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/yasuoza/YOChartImageKit#yochartimagekit).

[Sources](https://github.com/yasuoza/YOChartImageKit#yochartimagekit)